# Scipy modules can't be imported in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, import, scipy, pydev

I'm simply trying to import minimize from scipy.optimize as below:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
```

However, I always get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name optimize
```

What's the issue here? Am I missing dependencies or something? I am running PyDev version 3.4.1 within Eclipse Kepler. My scipy version is 0.14.0, and numpy version is 1.8.0.

Comment: Does the same statement work if you run Python from the command line?

Comment: Can you do `import scipy` and check that it imports in general?

Comment: @MattDMo Yes that statement works when I run from the command line.

Comment: @Ffisegydd no import scipy does not work either, the methods show up from the drop-down menu, but when I run the program I always get an ImportError

Comment: Do you have more than one Python installation? Could it be that when you use the command line you're using one and then when you run it in Eclipse it's using a different one? If scipy was only installed in one that could cause an issue.

Comment: I only have one installation of Python, 2.7